# How to write a onClick listener for a ListView?

Tags: android

This is my ArrayAdapter:

```
public class ListArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {


    public ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Activity activity = new Activity();
     TextView linkText;
     TextView linkDesc;

    public Context c;
    public ListArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<String> fiokiList, Object o) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, fiokiList);
        this.links = fiokiList;
        activity = (Activity) (o);
        c = context;
        //notifyDataSetChanged();

    } 

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView; 
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);



            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        }  

        final String link = this.links.get(position);


        linkText  = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.linkTitle0001);
    //  linkImageView = (SmartImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.faviconView0001);
        linkText.setText(link); 


        //ImageView imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    //  PieMenu pieMenu = new PieMenu(imgView, activity);
        //fl.addView(pieMenu);  



        return convertView; 



    }

}
```

I understand how to write an onClickListener for an entire item of a listView? I understand how to write one for each item, but I don't get how to do it for an view?

Comment: Do you mean to say, say for example, you want onClick listener for `linkText`??

Comment: Or I think he means clicking the whole `ListView` ?

Comment: I meant on click of the entire item of the list view and not just linktext

Answer (score 3):

Remove what you did inside your adapter and add this code inside the main activity from which you call the adatper

> setOnItemClickListener

is the function that you should call.

```
list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is, if i am not wrong, you want to set onClickListener() for the views that lies inside every Single ListView row. If this is true, then you simply need to set `OnCliCkListener()` in getView() method.

Example: You find your views in

```
if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_home, null);

                tv_title = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleRowHomeTitle);
                tv_time = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textViewSingleRowHomeTime);
                iv_checkbox = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSingleRowHomeCheckbox);

                convertView.setTag(new TaskViewHolder(tv_title, tv_time,
                        iv_checkbox));

            } else {

                TaskViewHolder viewHolder = (TaskViewHolder) convertView
                        .getTag();
                tv_title = viewHolder.get_tv_task_title();
                tv_time = viewHolder.get_tv_task_time();
                iv_checkbox = viewHolder.get_iv_task_checkbox();
            }
```

After this, you can set `OnClickListener()` as below:

```
tv_title.setClickable(true);
tv_title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

If you want the click event for the views inside ListView row, you need to implement it inside your custom Adapter's `getView()` method, else your ListView's onItemClickListener is to be implemented inside `OnCreate()` only.

Comment: but this is clicked only when I click on text. If the text is null, then the onClick won't work. I was thinking more of a long press onClick of the listView item.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mean event when click listview right ?? if yes use this::

```
name of your listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClicklistener(){
@override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,View view,int position,long id){
//event up to you 
//my event is
Toast.makeText(Context,text,duration)
}

});
```